# How to use the Keystone.js admin api (unauthed) in my app?

Tags: javascript, keystonejs

I was taking a look at this the docs on the [admin api](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/master/admin/server/api) and realized that it perfectly solves my case of using Keystone to power a SPA. However, I can't figure out a way to access the admin api routes from the api routes that I'm building without forcing an auth event first.

Anyone have suggestions for how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error I came to a solution that I'm pretty happy with. I took a good look at keystone/admin/server/app/createDynamicRouter.js and copied the functionality from there, and also duplicated keystone/admin/server/middleware/initList.js.